# Using multiple Ad Networks in AdMob Ad Requests

Tags: android, admob

I just registered on AdColony and implemented their SDK into my app in order to add the AdColony network in my AdMob mediation group's Waterfall Ad Sources. My question now is, do i need to create an ad request for both of these networks separately or does AdMob use any one of the two based on eCPM etc. ?

I already tried requesting and showing two separate ads from both networks using test-keys and each one loaded successfully but separately thus stacking the ads together. Does AdMob automatically solve this if i don't make separate requests and just use a normal e.g. InterstitialAdRequest from AdMob?

Comment: https://developers.mopub.com/ try mopub